# How to insert a shortcode in the Wordpress backend

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, shortcode

I need to insert a chat whatsapp button into the wordpress backend pages but I do not know how I can make it work. I tried to use this code but I could not:

```
function lh_add_whatsapp_js_code() {
?>
    <!-- Start of whatsapp code -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var yourHTML = '<div class="mydiv"><?php do_shortcode("[njwa_button id="1044"]");?></div>';
    document.getElementsByClassName('services-right')[0].innerHTML = yourHTML;
</script>
    <!-- End of Whatsapp code -->
<?php
}
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'lh_add_whatsapp_js_code' ); // For back-end
```

This code I put in the functions.php file of my child theme.

Comment: what happens? a lot of shortcodes do not work in the backend, for example because the plugins js and css are only enqueued in the frontend. it's worth a try though.  i think you have to put "echo do_shortcode()"

Comment: I tried with echo but it also did not work

    function lh_add_whatsapp_js_code() {
    echo do_shortcode('[njwa_button id="1044"]');
    }
    add_shortcode('do_shortcode', 'njwa_button id="1044');
    add_action( 'admin_footer', 'lh_add_whatsapp_js_code' ); // For back-end

Answer (score 0):

First at all I'm not an expert. I will post an example that works for me, you can modify it  as you need.

Step 1

Declare the whatssapp API as a regular script in to functions.php file into a function:

```
    Function anyname_function(){
  wp_enqueue_style( 'whatssapp','https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=593xxxxxxxx&text=Hi%21%20I%20Want%20information%20about%20you.' );
  wp_enqueue_style('fontawesome','https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');  //whatssap icon from bootstrap


}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'anyname_function');
```

Step 2

In the header.php file we write this piece of code

```
<!-- whatssapp icon -->

  <a id="whatssap"  class="float" target="_blank">
  <i class="fa fa-whatsapp my-float"></i>
  </a>

  <!-- end whatssap icon -->
```

Step 3

In your style.css file  you must define the styles, in my case, it only applies to mobile devices, so let see the example:

```
@media (max-width: 719px){

        #whatssap{
            display:block;
        }

        .float{
    position:fixed;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    bottom:40px;
    right:40px;
    background-color:#25d366;
    color:#FFF;
    border-radius:50px;
    text-align:center;
  font-size:30px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999;
  z-index:100;
}

.my-float{
    margin-top:16px;
}


.my-float{
    margin-top:16px;
}

}
```

That's it or you can download a plug-in from the wordpress website.